# RcppEigen and package size

Tags: rcpp

I am maintaining a package that uses `RcppEigen`. The package itself has a modest amount of code (+- 1000 lines at the moment).

What I don't understand is that the file size of my library is very large, leading to a file size of 14MB for my `<packagename>.so` and 11MB for `<packagename>.o`.

I would imagine that the package would link dynamically to `RcppEigen` libraries (thus keeping the size of the binaries of my package relatively small). But my guess instead it links the libraries statically into my .o and .so files.

- Am I correct that this is what happens?
- Can I/should I avoid this?
- If so, how?
  I see here ([RcppEigen.package.skeleton documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RcppEigen/versions/0.3.3.4.0/topics/RcppEigen.package.skeleton)) that NAMESPACE should include "a `useDynLib` directive"; it is also present in my NAMESPACE file)

(On a side note, when I submit to CRAN the large package size is NOTEd, but has not been cause for rejection.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. I have not checked, but I expect that the majority of packages using RcppEigen (or RcppArmadillo) get this NOTE. That's because Eigen (and Armadillo) is a *header-only library*, i.e. it is *not* dynamically linked. Instead the respective function is compiled into each `*.o` file. This is potentially even worse than static linking: If a function is used in multiple compilation units, it will end up in multiple `*.o` files, leading to multiple versions of the same function in the `*.so`. That is the price we all have to pay for the convenience of header-only libraries. Getting dynamic (or static) linking correct can be really difficult, in particular on Windows.

Concerning the `useDynLib`: If you look into the `NAMESPACE` file in your package, you should see a line like `useDynLib(<packagename> [...])`. That tells R to load the dynamic library associated with your package and is required for any R package using compiled code.